# Bootstrap Multiselect - Check Optgroup Checkbox

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using the [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) with enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true, allowing all options within optgroups to be toggled when the optgroup header checkbox is clicked.  In some instances I need to preselect the options, which can mean all options within an optgroup are selected.  However, I can't figure out how to check the optgroup header checkbox when this is the case.  I can get all the options within an optgroup selected, but not the optgroup header checkbox.  This forces the user to click it twice to deselect all options in that optgoup.  I could indicate in a hidden field which optgroups have all options selected, but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually check the optgroup header checkbox.  Any suggestions?
[image]

```
 $("select[id$='ddlLocation']").multiselect({
        enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        maxHeight: 200,
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            $("select[id$='ddlLocation']").multiselect("updateButtonText");
            $("select[id$='ddlLocation']").multiselect("updateSelectAll");
            var arrLocations = [];
            var locations = $("#ddlLocation option:selected"); 
            $(locations).each(function(index, location){
                arrLocations.push([$(this).val()]);
            });
            if (arrLocations.length > 0) {
                $("input[id$='hdfLocationIds']").val(arrLocations);
                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                prm._doPostBack("btnParticipantLookup", 'getUserCnt');
            }
        }
    });
    var locationIds = $("input[id$='hdfLocationIds']").val();
    if (locationIds.length > 0)
    {
        $("select[id$='ddlLocation']").multiselect("select", locationIds.split(","));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been integrated/fixed by now. You can find the corresponding example here (last example for the `enableClickableOptGroups` option): http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableClickableOptGroups. Remember to upgrade to the lastest master branch.